# Remote user adress with hidden form value option

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have problem with entering some php code that would print remote adress (ip) of user visiting website in html form "value" option.

I need this to send command using rcon from this repo

Already tried:

```
    <?php
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : 
    ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : 
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="something $ip";

    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="<?php print $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>"
```

none of them works

Post request is being send for this file.
https://pastebin.com/CyJvBhyR

I use this query repo from xPaw (RCON)

https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query

If someone know how to make it work like this:

send already set command with ip of user accesing website "somecommand UserRemoteIP" and send it using command.php rcon query.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

**Start learn php from scratch**

```
<?php echo $ip; ?>
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

Comment: It's not working when i add it to value option dude

command that is being executed after using this is "something <?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" Still not IP adress same with $ip it execute it as normal text.

Comment: Bump @refffffff